# Rails - Where I have to store data file (.dat) in my rails project - GeoIp City database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, organization, geoip

I just have a simple question about organisation.
I use MaxMind GeoIP solution and download the following file: GeoLiteCity.dat
For now, I store it in db/ but I would like to know where I have to store this kind of db?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally they are just text files, so you can store I where ever you want as long as your script can access it.

Comment: I think vendor is the most appropriate place. Thanks for your answer!