# Rails 3.1+ and GeoIP database file location/access

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, geoip

This question is related to [Rails - Where I have to store data file (.dat) in my rails project - GeoIp City database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268275/rails-where-i-have-to-store-data-file-dat-in-my-rails-project-geoip-city) . I have a rails 3.2 app. I am trying to run:

```
@geoip = GeoIP.new('GeoLiteCity.dat')
```

In one of my app's controllers. I unzipped the 'GeoLiteCity.dat' file into the /public folder. I am getting the error "No such file or directory - GeoLiteCity.dat".

I've experimented with putting it in the images assets pipeline folder and some random other places. I continue to get the same error. Not sure how to access this file. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or how to access it best with the assets pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

Try referencing it via the full path:

```
@geoip = GeoIP.new("#{Rails.root}/public/GeoLiteCity.dat")
```

On a side note, it's probably not a big deal, but I wouldn't put the file in your public directory.